# How to map select query of Oracle function which returns CURSOR

Tags: java, oracle, cursor, mybatis, ibatis

I have some Oracle function which returns SYS_REFCURSOR:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SOME_PKG.SOME_FUNCION ()
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
   REF_TEST   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN REF_TEST FOR
      SELECT COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME
        FROM SOME_TABLE;
   RETURN REF_TEST;
END;
```

Java bean:

```
public class Product {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Java mapper interface:

```
public interface ProductMapper {
    List<Product> getAll();
}
```

ProductMapper.xml:

```
...
<resultMap id="productResults" type="Product">
    <result property="id" column="COLUMN_ID" />
    <result property="name" column="COLUMN_NAME" />
</resultMap>

<select id="getAll" resultMap="productResults">
    select SOME_PKG.SOME_FUNCION from dual
</select>
```

If I execute SQL query "select SOME_PKG.SOME_FUNCION from dual" manually it returns 3 records

After calling "getAll" method I receive List with only one null element.

I am using MyBatis 3.2.3

What should I do to get a correct result?

Answer (score 2):

In case your not expecting result set use update tag and call function like that

```
<update id="getAll" statementType="CALLABLE">
        { #{holder.products, jdbcType=CURSOR, mode=OUT, resultMap=productResults, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet} = call SOME_PKG.SOME_FUNCION() }
</update>
```

but since products is an OUT parameter it should be passed as one, most probably you'll have to modify mapper

```
public class Holder {
    public List<Products> products;
}

public class Mapper {
    void getAll(Holder holder);
}
```